# Include variable in python script that invokes MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am attempting to include variable in python script that invokes MS SQL Server

```
import pyodbc

ip_addr = '10.10.10.10'

querystring = """SELECT USER_NAME
FROM sem6.sem_computer, [sem6].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], sem6.IDENTITY_MAP, sem6.SEM_CLIENT
WHERE [sem6].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
AND sem6.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
AND sem6.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = %s
"""

params = (ip_addr)

con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.100;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PWD=password')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(querystring, params)
result = cur.fetchone()[0]
print result
con.commit()
con.close()
```

And it gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute(querystring, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameter
s were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Comment: In your current code, `params` is not a tuple, it's a string equal to `ip_addr`. In order to make a one-item tuple, you need a trailing comma, as in `params = (ip_addr,)`.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I tried this, and am receiving same error

Comment: I didn't expect that was the cause of your problem. It was just an error I noticed. That's why it was a comment.

Comment: What if you use a '?' instead of a '%s'?

Comment: @Matt using ? without quotes will work!

Comment: Is it okay if I put that for the answer?

Comment: @Matt yes, please put that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ? instead of %s in your original query.